# convert the time columns to DolphinDB TIME when importing live market data

Tags: data-conversion, dolphindb

When importing a CSV file containing live market data to DolphinDB, how to convert the time columns to the DolphinDB TIME type time in DolphinDB? For example, the csv file contains a time value 093000000 which will be parsed as a string if I import the file with loadText. How can I convert it to 09:30:00.000, the TIME data type?

Answer (score 0):

If you have imported the data into DolphinDB, use `temporalParse` to convert strings to temporal types in DolphinDB.

```
temporalParse( "093000000", "HHmmssSSS")
```

If you haven't yet imported the CSV file, use `loadText`. Use the schema parameter to specify the time format of the temporal column.
Check the code sample below:

```
schema = extractTextSchema("yourFilePath");
update schema set type="TIME" where name = "yourTimeColumnName"  //modify the data type of a specified column
update schema set format=""  // Add a format column to the variable schema
update schema set format="HHmmssSSS" where name = "yourTimeColumnName" // Modify the time format of the specified TIME column
loadText("yourFilePath",,schema)
```